# How to allocate memory dynamically using pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have the following task:
Creat a program that will transform array A to array B in the followin order:
http://gyazo.com/29e434ebdc1e235fe0fc97c26ae9fe9c

The size of A is entered by user, as well the elements. Print the new elements of B. "Use pointers"

Examples: If I input 1234567, the program will output 8888888.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;
    cout << "Enter the size of array" << endl;
    cin >> N;
    int A[N], B[N];
    cout << "Enter the elements of the array" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        cin >> A[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        B[i] = A[i] + A[N-i-1];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        cout << B[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is only one problem I have, it says to "use pointers" but I don't know where shall I use them and they must be used... thanks in advance.

Comment: Read more about the `new` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int A[N], B[N];
```

This code is non-standard (when `N` is a variable). Your compiler allows that, but if you try to compile this code in other one, it probably won't work.

Using pointers in this case means, that you should allocate memory for the arrays dynamically, eg.

```
int * A, * B;
A = new int[N];
B = new int[N];
```

This code is valid in terms of C++ standard.

Remember though, that you will have to free allocated memory manually after you don't need it anymore:

```
delete[] A;
delete[] B;
```

This should work with the rest of your code left unchanged, since `[]` operator works for pointers as well.

And finally, if you really are writing a C++ program, you surely should be using `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays...

---

**Edit:** (in response to comment)

If you declare a variable in the following way:

```
int * A;
```

And then write:

```
cin >> *(A + i);
```

It means:

1. Read data from user and parse it;
2. Go `i` "steps" starting from address A (it actually "walks" `i * sizeof(*A)` bytes from A).
3. Put the data read from the user to memory pointed to by place evaluated in step 2.

But when you declare:

```
int (*A)[N];
```

The A becames pointer to the array of N elements. Since array is convertible to a pointer to its first element, you may think of that previous line (for the sake of explanation) as

```
int ** A;
```

In such case compiler tries to do the same as I described earlier. But now it walks `i` *pointers* starting from A, not *int*s. Then it dereferences that pointer getting an `int *` and attempts to put there data written by user. But `>>` operator of `cin` is not able to translate text to a pointer and that's why compiler complains.

---

**Foot note**

While you're learning using pointers, you may think of `<something> variable[]` as being equal to `<something> * variable` pointing to the first element of that array. This is a *lie* (because array is not *a* pointer, but it's *convertible* to a pointer to its first element), but helps understanding what arrays do have in common with pointers. That's why you can think of

```
int (* A)[];
```

As a

```
int ** A;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. One question, when I use the `new` operator, I can use this line: `cin >> *(A + i);`, but when it's normally declared like `int (*A)[N]`, I can't. Can you explain me why is that?

Comment: So, basically, according to updated comment, if I declare it as `int (*A)[N]`, there is no way to get the input by user using cin, because it's not possible to take pointer as an input in C++ (using cin)? I have to use the new operator (the only way to solve this task using pointers)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, this

```
cin >> N; 
int A[N], B[N];
```

is not valid ANSI C++. You cannot declare arrays with variable indices. So you need a way to declare variable length arrays, and one way is to use pointers and dynamically allocated memory using new[] (and then delete[]).

The other, preferable method would be to use a container such as std::vector.